# how to ban someone in discord using JDA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, discord-jda

how do I ban someone in discord using JDA? I tried many times but doesn't work.
I'm trying to make a bot in java JDA and I want to implement a command where a admin can ban a user using the bot.

this is my base code for the ban command:

```
String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+"); // gets message from mod and splits every whitespace.

if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "ban")) {
    // ban code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Guild#ban`](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.dv8tion/JDA/latest/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#ban(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member,int,java.lang.String)) (e.g. using a `Member`):

```java
Guild guild=event.getGuild();
Member member=event.getMentionedMembers().get(0);//TODO check if exists
guild.ban(member,0,"ban command").queue();
```

This bans the `Member` from the guild with the reason `ban command` without deleting any messages.

If the second argument is not `0`, discord will delete all messages from the user sent in the last n days (where n is the argument)

The message is optional and you can also use a `User` or an id instead of the member.

Integrated in your code, it could look like this:

```java
String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+"); // gets message from mod and splits every whitespace.

if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "ban")) {
    if(args.length==1){//no argument
        //error message
    }
    else if(event.getMentionedMembers().isEmpty()){//no mentioned members, try to use argument as ID
        event.getGuild().ban(args[1],0,"ban command").queue();
    }else{//mentioned members
        
        event.getGuild().ban(event.getMentionedMembers().get(0),0,"ban command").queue();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: can you give me a code based on the edit?

Comment: Like this? Note that this is just one possibility.

Comment: You need to say what doesn't work. Note that the bot needs to have the `BAN_MEMBERS` permission and the highest role of the bot needs to be higher than the highest role of the user to ban.

Comment: i gave the bot admin permission. this is what comes up when i use the ban command in discord:

The specified ID is not a valid snowflake (<@!830335252177616916>). Expecting a valid long value!

Comment: You can try with `getMentionedUsers()` instead of `getMentionedMembers()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to do with (and without) an ID, This answer might help.

```java
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix+"ban") && !event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
            try {
             Member target = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0);
             if (!event.getMember().canInteract(target) || !event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
               event.getChannel().sendMessage("You don't have the required permission to ban this member!").queue();
               return;
             }
 
             final Member selfMember = event.getGuild().getSelfMember();

             if (!selfMember.canInteract(target) || !selfMember.hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
               event.getChannel().sendMessage("I don't have the required permission to kick this member!").queue();
               return;
             }
                
             event.getGuild().ban(target, 0, "REASON").queue();
             event.getChannel().sendMessage(target.getUser().getName()+" has been banned successfully.").queue();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                try {
                     User target = Main.jda.getUserById(args[1]);
                     if (!event.getMember().canInteract(event.getGuild().getMember(target)) || !event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
                       event.getChannel().sendMessage("You don't have the required permission to ban this member!").queue();
                       return;
                     }
         
                     final Member selfMember = event.getGuild().getSelfMember();

                     if (!selfMember.canInteract(event.getGuild().getMember(target)) || !selfMember.hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
                       event.getChannel().sendMessage("I don't have the required permission to kick this member!").queue();
                       return;
                     }
                        
                     event.getGuild().ban(target, 0, "REASON").queue();
                     event.getChannel().sendMessage("User has been banned successfully.").queue();
                    }catch(Exception ex2) {
                        event.getChannel().sendMessage("The user is not in the server, Or Invalid ID").queue();
                    }   
            }
     }
```

It first checks if the mention is there, If not, It'll actually cause an exception, So `try` & `catch` will help, If it failed, The bot will check for an ID, if it's not there, It'll send a reason.
Note : The `target` variable in the ID area starts with `Main.jda`, where `Main` is the main class where your bot is (Token, Status), `jda` is your `JDA` variable.

Leave a comment if you have any questions.